# Python Foursquare API Wrapper - TypeError __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'clientId'

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to deploy my Django project through pythonAnywhere. 
So far, I run the command

```
./manage.py migrate
./manage.py runserver
```

It returns no error. And when go my site, I can see my homepage as I normally see when I connect from localhost:8000

There are two input boxes for user to enter the type of food he wants (pizza or ice cream for ex.) and the location (city to look up) and result will be listed (pizza places in New York for example) I used Foursquare api to get the results.

When I try from my localhost, everything works fine. But when I try to search from .pythonanywhere.com it gives an error and the weird thing is the error is changing its parameter although I did not change anything.

The error :

```
TypeError at /
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'clientId'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://jinxed.pythonanywhere.com/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'clientId'
Exception Location: /home/jinxed/Foursquare-API-with-Django/indexapp/views.py in index, line 37
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['/var/www',
 '.',
 '',
 '/var/www',
 '/home/jinxed/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.4',
 '/home/jinxed/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/jinxed/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/jinxed/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
 '/home/jinxed/Foursquare-API-with-Django']
Server time:    Fri, 27 Jan 2017 14:20:45 +0300
```

and my views.py is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from indexapp.forms import IndexForm
from foursquare import Foursquare
from indexapp.models import Database



def index(request):

    f_food = ''
    f_location = ''
    fs_result = []
    error = ''
    searched_dict = []

    # check whether the parameters coming through input fields or search history panel

    if request.method == 'POST':  # from input fields
        iForm = IndexForm(request.POST)

        if iForm.is_valid():

            f_food = iForm.cleaned_data['food']
            f_location = iForm.cleaned_data['location']
        else:
            error = 'Invalid form'

    elif request.GET.get('query') is not None and request.GET.get('location') is not None: # from search history panel
        f_food = request.GET.get('query')
        f_location = request.GET.get('location')


    # if I do not get any f_food at all, that means parameters are still in their initial values
    if f_food is not '':
        fs = Foursquare(clientId = 'XXXXXXX',
                        clientSecret = 'XXXXXX',
                        version = '20170127')

        fs.veneus(f_food, f_location)
        fs_meta = fs.getMeta()

        if fs_meta['code'] != 200:  # meta = 200 for successful, 400 for failure
            error = "Unsuccessful data"

        else:
            fs_result = fs.getPlaces() # this is keeping the veneus dict
            d = Database(food = f_food, location = f_location) # same as the INSERT INTO
            d.save()
            last_twenty = Database.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:20]  # take the last 20 search
            searched_dict = last_twenty.values() # turn it to a array of dictionaries

    # clear the searched history
    if request.GET.get('delete') == '1':
        Database.objects.all().delete()


    return render(request, "index.html",{'error': error, 'results': fs_result,
                                           'f_f': f_food,'f_l': f_location,
                                           'searched_dict': searched_dict})
```

you see that line 37 contains "version='20170127'"

Can anyone help me with this ?

Thank you so much

**EDIT**

Here is my foursquare.py where I handled the names (client_ıd etc..)

```
import requests

class Foursquare:

    def __init__(self, clientId, clientSecret, version):
        self.cId = clientId
        self.cSecret = clientSecret
        self.cVersion = version
        self.results = {}

    def veneus(self, q, n):
        prm = {'query': q,
                'near': n,
                'client_id': self.cId,
                'client_secret': self.cSecret,
                'v': self.cVersion
                }
        r = requests.get('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search', params=prm)
        self.results = r.json() # take it as an json object

    def getPlaces(self):
        return self.results['response']['venues']

    def getMeta(self): # to see if we are getting the unsuccessful data
        return self.results['meta']
```

**EDIT 2**

Layout of files is like that

```
Foursquare-API-with-Django
|
|---backend---
|            |- __init__.py
|            |- settings.py
|            |- urls.py
|            |- wsgi.py
|
|---indexapp--
|            |- __init__.py
|            |- admin.py
|            |- apps.py
|            |- forms.py
|            |- foursquareT.py
|            |- models.py
|            |- tests.py
|            |- urls.py
|            |- views.py
|-- manage.py
```

Thank you

Comment: It's telling you that the Foursquare class doesn't take a `clientId` parameter.

Comment: But it has. I edited my question with adding my Foursquare class.

Comment: Are you sure the code is using your class and not the third-party library?

Comment: And it is actually working on my localhost. I only get this with pythonanywhere.

Comment: There must be a difference between your localhost and server (e.g. different Python version/different packages installed in virtual environment/differences in files). We don't have access to either environment, so we can't help you figure out what the difference is.

Comment: After you said that, I uninstalled foursquare package and rename the files as I explained below under the answer as comment, but now, it does not recognize the file when I say import

Comment: I thought that it might be version difference between django's which I use. I deleted all the files and setup both virtualenv. and django again. I think if I find out why it does not recognize my renamed file, it would be solved. Thank you

Comment: can it be for this: I setup my settings.py file's database part as `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql'` but when I installing database to pythonanywhere, it prompted me to use `pip install mysqlclient` so should I change my engine? if yes, to what?

Comment: No, you don't need to change database engine. The `django.db.backends.mysql` backend requires `mysqlclient` for Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://github.com/mLewisLogic/foursquare#authentication) for the foursquare api show that you should be using `client_id` and `client_secret`, instead of `clientId` and `clientSecret`.

```
fs = Foursquare(client_id='XXXXXXX',
                client_secret='XXXXXX',
                version='20170127',
)
```

Comment: I handled that in the class Foursquare located in the foursquare.py with an init function. Editted my question so you can see what I am saying.

Comment: It sounds like your code is not importing your class when you do `from foursquare import Foursquare`. Try uninstalling the third party library if you are not using it. To be sure, you can rename your `foursquare.py` to `myfoursquare.py` and do `from myfoursquare import Foursquare`.

Comment: Actually I just what did you said I renamed my `foursquare.py` as `foursquareT.py` and renamed the class name as `FoursquareT`. And of course I changed the import section as  `from foursquareT import FoursquareT` but now, I am getting an `error : no module named foursquareT`

Comment: Please update your question with the layout of the files in your project.

Comment: I edited my question by adding the tree structure of my files

Comment: Try a relative import `from .foursquare import Foursquare` (adjust for renamed module/class)

Comment: I did it. Now `./manage.py migrate` says No migration to apply and when I reload the site, pythonanywhere.com says `Something went wrong :-(` instead of my homepage as it did, with an error code : `Unhandled Exception`

Comment: If you've fixed the issue with the foursquare import, it sounds like you might have a separate issue that would be better as a separate question. You need the full traceback from the logs/debug page/admin email - `Unhandled Exception` isn't enough. I would expect "No migration to apply", since you said you already ran `migrate` before you hit the foursquare issue.

Comment: Yes. I am going to inspect the Error.log file and if the problem keeps going, I will ask it in other question. Thank you so much for your help!